# Subquery in jOOQ is using the DEFAULT dialect instead of configured dialect

Tags: java, jooq

jOOQ version: 3.15.3

I have a jOOQ update query that uses a subquery to set the value:

```
myDslContext.update(TICKET)
    .set(TICKET.TICKET_STATUS, BillingStatus.POSTED)
    .set(TICKET.INVOICE, myDslContext.select(AR_INVOICE.INVOICE)
        .from(AR_INVOICE)
        .where(AR_INVOICE.CUSTID.eq(TICKET.CUSTID))
        .and(AR_INVOICE.STATUS.eq(BillingStatus.PRINTED)))
    .where(TICKET.INVOICE.isNull())
    .and(TICKET.TICKET_STATUS.eq(BillingStatus.PRINTED))
    .andExists(myDslContext.select(AR_INVOICE.INVOICE)
        .from(AR_INVOICE)
        .where(AR_INVOICE.CUSTID.eq(TICKET.CUSTID))
        .and(AR_INVOICE.STATUS.eq(BillingStatus.PRINTED)))
    .execute();
```

The BillingStatus enum makes use of a custom binding. When implementing the jOOQ Binding interface, one must write code to render the value in SQL. As such, my code checks the context configuration and throws an exception if the SQLDialect is not what is expected.

```
@Override
public void sql(BindingSQLContext<T> ctx) throws SQLException {
  Short converted = converter().to(ctx.value());

  if (ctx.family() == SQLDialect.INFORMIX) {
    if (ctx.render().paramType() == ParamType.INLINED) {
      if (converted == null) {
        ctx.render().sql("NULL");
      } else {
        ctx.render().sql(String.valueOf(converted));
      }
    } else {
      ctx.render().sql(ctx.variable());
    }
  } else {
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

However in the context of the subqueries I am seeing the BindingSQLContext configuration with dialect `DEFAULT` instead of the expected `INFORMIX`. I could simply remove the Dialect check, but in the very near future we intend to move this code to a different database, so that feels like I might need that going forward. Regardless of my desire to validate the dialect, I still believe the dialect should be set correctly here as there could be other cases where dialect-specific code is required.

I get the same results using the static DSL.select() as opposed to using my configured DSLContext `myDslContext`

I am currently stuck on jOOQ 3.15 because, for the moment, we have other blockers for moving from Spring Boot 2.x to 3.x where we could use a newer jOOQ version.

Am I doing the subquery completely wrong, or is this a bug? If it's a bug, is there a workaround?

**UPDATE**:

Here is the full stack trace from my failing integration test:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: Error while generating SQL for Binding

    at org.jooq.impl.Val.accept(Val.java:185)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:720)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:296)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.lambda$visit$2(AbstractContext.java:832)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.toggle(AbstractContext.java:333)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.paramType(AbstractContext.java:845)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:832)
    at org.jooq.impl.CompareCondition.accept0(CompareCondition.java:214)
    at org.jooq.impl.CompareCondition.accept(CompareCondition.java:159)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:720)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:296)
    at org.jooq.impl.CombinedCondition.accept(CombinedCondition.java:231)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:720)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:296)
    at org.jooq.impl.ConditionProviderImpl.accept(ConditionProviderImpl.java:127)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:720)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:296)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.toSQLReference0(SelectQueryImpl.java:2349)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.lambda$toSQLReferenceLimitDefault$21(SelectQueryImpl.java:1865)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.toggle(AbstractContext.java:333)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.data(AbstractContext.java:344)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.toSQLReferenceLimitDefault(SelectQueryImpl.java:1865)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.accept0(SelectQueryImpl.java:1779)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.accept(SelectQueryImpl.java:1435)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:720)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:296)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.render(DefaultDSLContext.java:709)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.hash(Tools.java:3256)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.autoAlias(Tools.java:3233)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.asTable(SelectQueryImpl.java:668)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.fieldsRow(SelectQueryImpl.java:661)
    at org.jooq.impl.FieldsTrait.fields(FieldsTrait.java:57)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.dataTypes(Tools.java:3439)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.scalarType(Tools.java:3443)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.asField(SelectQueryImpl.java:646)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.asField(SelectImpl.java:2921)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdateImpl.set(UpdateImpl.java:154)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdateImpl.set(UpdateImpl.java:122)
    at com.mycompany.api.service.impl.CreateInvoiceRecordsHelperServiceImpl.postInvoices(CreateInvoiceRecordsHelperServiceImpl.java:61)
    at com.mycompany.api.service.impl.CreateInvoiceRecordsHelperServiceImpl.createInvoiceRecords(CreateInvoiceRecordsHelperServiceImpl.java:54)
    at com.mycompany.api.service.impl.CreateInvoiceRecordsHelperServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$73261fc1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.mycompany.api.service.impl.CreateInvoiceRecordsHelperServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$378b940a.createInvoiceRecords(<generated>)
    at com.mycompany.api.service.impl.ArInvoiceServiceImpl.createInvoiceRecords(ArInvoiceServiceImpl.java:137)
    at com.mycompany.api.service.impl.ArInvoiceServiceImplIT.testCreateInvoiceRecords(ArInvoiceServiceImplIT.java:185)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at com.mycompany.jooq.binding.AbstractSmallintEnumBinding.sql(AbstractSmallintEnumBinding.java:42)
    at com.mycompany.jooq.binding.BillingStatusBinding.sql(BillingStatusBinding.java:7)
    at org.jooq.impl.Val.accept(Val.java:182)
    ... 122 more
```

Comment: Are you sure the call to your binding with `SQLDialect.DEFAULT` is really relevant (as opposed to being caused by some internal logging `toString()` call, for example)? I.e. what's the complete stacktrace of your `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`?

Comment: Post updated with stack trace @LukasEder

Comment: @LukasEder There is no internal logging other than org.jooq DEBUG in my test environment. Even with jOOQ logging off, the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, and as you can see in your stack trace, the unexpected call to your binding using `SQLDialect.DEFAULT` originates from a bit of internal code that isn't necessarily dialect specific, namely:

```java
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.render(DefaultDSLContext.java:709)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.hash(Tools.java:3256)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.autoAlias(Tools.java:3233)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.asTable(SelectQueryImpl.java:668)
```

An alias is being generated for the subquery in order to access its fields (as if it were a derived table). This doesn't really affect your `INFORMIX` specific SQL that much. Now, it may or may not be a bug for this hash operation to ignore the `SQLDialect`, I'm not sure yet (you could report an issue if this behaviour still persists with the latest versions of jOOQ).

Note that in jOOQ 3.17, an improvement was implemented to help avoid the potentially slow call to `TableLike::asTable` when it isn't strictly necessary (e.g. in your case, probably):

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13349

In any case, your `Binding` shouldn't throw an exception on `SQLDialect.DEFAULT`. There may be other reasons why the `SQLDialect` isn't set to your configured dialects, e.g. when logging things or any other case where SQL is being rendered without access to your `Configuration`.

> we have other blockers for moving from Spring Boot 2.x to 3.x where we could use a newer jOOQ version.

I'm not sure if Spring Boot 2.x really prevents your upgrade to a more recent version of jOOQ. Spring Boot interacts with jOOQ only very superficially (creating a `Configuration` for you), and jOOQ is quite backwards compatible, so I doubt that Spring Boot would even notice your upgrade of jOOQ.